# EXC_BAD_ACCESS only when building object inside function

Tags: c++

I'm working on a C++ project in XCode and I'm getting what appears to be some strange behavior (based on how I understand it). Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class beep {
public:
    virtual void greet() {
        std::cout << "bleep\n";
    }
};

class boop : public beep {
public:
    void greet() {
        std::cout << "bloop\n";
    }
};

class beep_master {
public:
    std::vector<beep*> beeps;

    void beep_everything() {
        for (int i = 0; i < beeps.size(); i++) {
            beeps[i]->greet();
        }
    }
};

beep_master factory() {
    boop boop1;
    boop boop2;

    beep_master master;
    master.beeps.push_back(&boop1);
    master.beeps.push_back(&boop2);

    return master;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    beep_master master = factory();

    beep_master* ref = &master;

    ref->beep_everything();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm running this via XCode, and I'm getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in the `for`-loop in `beep_master`. Everywhere I've looked on the internet seems to indicate this is due to some memory management issues but I'm not really allocating anything dynamically.

I've noticed that if I move the contents of `factory` into `main` that I no longer get the error which leads me to believe it has something to do with `boop1` and `boop2` going out of scope and making the pointers invalid after the code exits that function.

Noodling on this, I'm beginning to think that this issue is unavoidable without the use of dynamic memory via the `new` operator and `shared_ptr`. Is this the right direction, or am I missing something in my setup here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. The `factory` function is storing pointers to local variables `boop1` and `boop2` which go away when the function returns, so you're left with pointers that point to invalid data.

You're pretty much going to have to dynamically allocate your objects to store the pointers in your vector.

Comment: That makes sense, but I also found it surprising that if my objects happened to have a property, that value _is still set properly after returning_, at least immediately afterwards. This may be "typical behavior", or an LLVM specific behavior. I just found it interesting.

Comment: @ChipBell The default destructors for your local objects, which are called when the function scope ends, are likely to do the smallest amount of work possible and will not likely actually modify any object members. So after the return you have pointers to memory locations that now contain remnants of destroyed objects. Any subsequent function call is very likely to overwrite those locations with new data.